# How to call model from public folder in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, public

I'm trying to call add an item to a model through my public folder in Laravel but I'm getting this error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function connection() on null in [..]/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php`

Here is the file in my public folder:

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'../../../bootstrap/autoload.php';
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use \App\Models\Cdr;

$id_ex = '11';
$cdr = new Cdr();
$cdr->id_ex = $id_ex;
$cdr->save();
```

Do I need to start the app somehow before this? I've also tried calling a method inside a controller from the public folder, but it gives me the same error. For example:

```
CdrController::storeCdr($id_ex);
```

My model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cdr extends Model
{

    public $table = 'cdr';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    public $fillable = [];
    public $guarded = ['id'];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [];

    /**
     * Validation rules
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $rules = [];
}
```

Comment: Isn't it `require __DIR__.'../bootstrap/autoload.php';`? Or have you put some other folders inside of public?

Comment: Yes, I'm working in a sub-folder of public, that shouldn't affect this right?

Comment: No it shouldn't. I have figured out what's going on, typing my answer now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your script hasn't got a clue of it's environment. It doesn't know there is a database or even a framework for that matter, you have to actually boot the app to make this information available.

You can do this with

```
$app = require __DIR__ . '../../../bootstrap/app.php';
```

If this doesn't work, you need to boot at least the ConsoleKernel. Check `app/Console/Kernel.php` and it's superclass `ConsoleKernel` for an example how to do that.

Comment: Exactly my problem. Thanks Loek.

Comment: Glad I could be of help, learned a bit more about Laravel in the process too haha

Comment: @Loek There is single quote missing before the semicolon.